# nawk whitespace trim with multiple condition

Tags: shell, unix, nawk

temp_file.txt

```
|112233456543214 |
|154233456873221|
|154233456868320|
```

When i am using the below nawk command i saw the data is skipping if you have the empty space so i have to trim the white space .I have to include the white space trim in the below command(Know to use nwak command alone)that is the challenge.The question i have is to how include the white space trim in the below command

```
nawk -F '|' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}(length($2) >=13){
  $2=substr($2,1,6)"xxxxxx"substr($2,length($2)-3)}1' temp_file.txt>tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt temp_file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the first char is a pipe, your `$1` will always be **an empty string**. You want to examine `$2` for your data.

```
awk -F\| -v OFS=\| '{gsub(/(^[[:blank:]]+)|([[:blank:]]+$)/, "", $2)} 1' <<END
|112233456543214 |
|  154233456873221  |
| 154233456868320|
END
```

```
|112233456543214|
|154233456873221|
|154233456868320|
```

If you're using `-F`, you don't also need to define FS in a BEGIN block.

---

If you want it spelled out:

```
$ nawk -F '|' '
    BEGIN {OFS = FS}
    function obfuscate(string) {
        gsub(/(^[[:blank:]]+)|([[:blank:]]+$)/, "", string)
        return substr(string,1,6) "xxxxxx" substr(string,length(string)-3)
    }
    length($2) >= 13 {$2 = obfuscate($2) }
    1
' <<END
|112233456543214 |
|  154233456873221  |
|123456789012|
|1234567890123|
|12345678901234|
| 154233456868320|
END
```

```
|112233xxxxxx3214|
|154233xxxxxx3221|
|123456789012|
|123456xxxxxx0123|
|123456xxxxxx1234|
|154233xxxxxx8320|
```

Comment: The question is how to include the trim in the command  nawk -F '|' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}(length($1) >=13){
  $1=substr($1,1,6)"xxxxxx"substr($1,length($1)-3)}1' temp_file.txt>tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt temp_file.txt

Comment: Done. Use `tmp=$(mktemp)` instead of "tmp.txt"

Comment: Or you can use the OP's `BEGIN` assignment and omit the `-F`. Your first example shows "x" substitutions but you omitted the functionality to do it.

Comment: Thanks @DennisWilliamson, bad cut'n'paste

Answer (score 0):

`nawk` supports regular expressions in the definition of `FS`. You can use this to trim the leading and trailing spaces or tabs.

```
nawk -F '[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*' 'BEGIN{OFS = "|"} (length($2) >= 13) {
    $2 = substr($2, 1, 6) "xxxxxx" substr($2, length($2) - 3)}1'
```

The pipe is surrounded by square brackets to prevent it from acting as the regex alternation operator. The regex says to use the combination of zero or more blanks (space or tab) followed by a pipe character followed by zero or more blanks as the field separator.

Comment: @Denis Thx .I tried applying the same command but i don't see that is working .It is skipping the "x" substitution logic

Comment: @Senthil: It works for me. What version is your `nawk`? Mine is `/usr/bin/nawk -> /etc/alternatives/nawk -> /usr/bin/gawk` which may explain why it works. However, the Sun `nawk` man page says that `FS` supports regular expressions. Do glenn jackman's examples work for you? (or perhaps it's his first example, which is completely missing "x" substitution, which is causing you problems and not mine)